# How to add a proxy server in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, proxy

I have recently installed Windows Server 2008 R2 on a system.

Now I want to add a proxy server so that all the clients added to this can only visit the websites I describe.

How can i do this?

Comment: Your tag says 2008 R2, but your question says 2008. Can you please fix this discrepancy. They are very different operating systems.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Server Fault.  Please review the [FAQ] before posting questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an argument of policy and how you treat your employees, but that's a separate issue.

If you're looking at doing something like this, you do it by deploying a proxy server product and using that system as a gateway. @MarkM mentioned Squid, which we've done before,using SquidGuard, but it won't block access to https sites. You'd most likely want a turnkey product that can handle proxying and filtering, using invisible proxying so there are no settings put in by the client machines or policy.

Personally you may run into issues by locking your employees down this much and treating them the way we do unless you have a really good reason to sink management time and money into this level. We do this because we're required by CIPA laws as a school...I'm sure if you're a three letter agency for the government you may have a good reason to do this too. Otherwise you might get some pushback from your employees...or at least turnover. But that's all I'll warn about.

Comment: I have found certain employees uploading the code to thier gmail server and so and so... and the chating at facebook when i am not in office

Comment: Again, this is a policy question, not a technical one. You can just pull the plug on the Internet if you wanted. They could just chat with their phones. The key question is whether they're getting the work done or not. Personally I wouldn't care if they're holding a NERF shootout in the office as long as the assigned work was getting done...heck, it might lift morale if they're working hard to keep things rolling.

Comment: @kishorejangid GMail and Facebook don't harm productivity; very similar to the fact that guns don't kill people, people kill people. If the employees want to screw off, they'll find a way, facebook or not. If it's impacting productivity, time to get rid of the employee.

Comment: what if they theft the coding of the company

Comment: If you make the working conditions miserable, you're going to have a hard time finding and holding on to talent. If there are problems you can deal with it on a personal basis. And again, that's an opinion. But I'm sure there would be others that agree.

Comment: I'm so coming to work for you when you get that shootout going.

Comment: You're going to stop someone from reverse engineering the code? If they steal the code, you can sue them. You can probably ask about this in the OnStartups exchange. But if they want to steal your code, A) it came from their heads to start with, B) they could stick the code on USB drives or a number of other ways than GMail.

Comment: You might even encourage people to steal your code by making work conditions miserable...just a side note.

Comment: @kishorejangid If they want to steal code, they will. Removable media, printing documents, sending e-mails, heck they might even memorize the code... Comes right back to: hire good employees, don't try to force bad employees to be good.

Answer (score 9):

There is no Microsoft role built into Server 2008 to make it act like a proxy. You can use [TMG](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/forefront/threat-management-gateway-overview.aspx), but it's not free. Something like [Squid on Windows](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/Windows) might be worth looking at, but it's not native to the platform, so it could be kludgey down the road.

Honestly, there is no good `step by step` guide, as you have requested. Everyone's environment is different. If you don't know how to set up a proxy, or even how to license and install one, I suggest you hire a consultant that has experience with this.

Comment: mine is a small company and want my employee to be restricted to visit only programming websiteremoving access to social networking sites and email sites..

Comment: @kishorejangid I'm not sure what that has to do with my answer. It certainly doesn't change it. No one here is going to do your job for you. If you don't even have a starting point for how to implement something, then hire someone that does.

Comment: @kishorejangid Trying to keep your employees on task by blocking websites has been found to be counterproductive in many studies. Further, consider how much time you're investing in blocking the sites. You would be **much** better off simply requiring employees to complete a certain amount of work in a reasonable time frame; deal with employees who fail to obtain this.

Comment: @kishorejangid You should read the [faq] and [how to ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting again. This is a site for **professional** administrators. As a professional, we assume that when you come here to ask, you will have done research and testing on your own. We expect you to have specific questions with details about what you've tried or what **exactly** you're trying to accomplish. Your question is amazingly broad and you've, apparently, done **no** research. It's an insult to us for you to come and ask questions that amount to "do my job for me".

Comment: I did researched on google and not find any solution for my question...

Comment: **why u people down voting my question** - because it's a very badly written question and therefore a poor fit for Server Fault's normal question standards. Next question?

Comment: sorry to all... I regret

Comment: @kishorejangid No you didn't. Please don't insult us and say that "research" is a few minutes of googling. Research is reading documentation, calling vendors, meeting with sales engineers, etc. I stick by my original comment. We **will not** do your job for you. We all get paid for our time and **voluntarily** contribute to this community. We expect that you will have met certain requirements before you ask a question here and the most basic requirement is that you have a clue about what you're asking.